# How to extract Cookie Data from Jmeter Request

Tags: regex, jmeter

On Jmeter: `View Result tree`: Request: Raw

```
Cookie Data:
.ASPXAUTH=EBB383A4DA12F0C106F044F70EC6CD6637252490DA31179407C466B8933D8B32622584F7A9F18A40C9D423078313E6ACB89519497CDDED451AF0C857AF3D6ED1C12296E56CE7D6058D7450E74B845EE39F3404925F679F180493329BDA021698
```

Regular expression extractor

```
Main Sampler Only
Request Headers
Regular Expression : Cookie Data:(.*)
Template : $1$
Match No : 1
```

Still getting `Null` Value

Also tryed with

```
Cookie Data:\n(.*)
```

Please Suggest.

Comment: Please format properly your question.

Comment: Try `Cookie Data:\r?\n(.*)` if the line breaks can be both in Windows and Linux style. Or even `Cookie Data:(?:\r\n?|\n)(.*)`

Comment: Do you really want Cookie Data from Request Headers? Or Response Headers?

Comment: From Request header only.

Answer (score 6):

Given the value is stored in the [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager), you can access it using below steps:

1. Add `CookieManager.save.cookies=true` line to *user.properties* file
2. Restart JMeter to pick the property up
3. Access the cookie value as `${COOKIE_.ASPXAUTH}` where required.

See [Using the HTTP Cookie Manager in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) article for more detailed explanation of the above steps

Answer (score 3):

In Regular Expression Extractor, under `Field to check`, please select `Response Headers` radio button.

---

To save Cookies automatically, In `jmeter.properties` file, set as following:

```
CookieManager.save.cookies=true
```

Restart Jmeter.

You can access the saved cookies with `COOKIE` prefix.

example (in your case):

```
${COOKIE_Cookie_Data} # confirm the same in debug sampler result in View Results Tree
```

I strongly suggest adding `Debug Sampler` & `View Results Tree`, which shows the saved cookie values.

Answer (score 1):

Try "Cookie Data:\n(.+)" as your regex.

- = Anything In ()
- = At least one character in ()